# ¿Como pueda evitar que al pasar de Form1 a Form2, no me borre lo que esta en el Form1?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo varios Form's dentro de mi proyecto, lo que deseo es que cuando paso de un form a otro el primero que tenia seleccionado no me borre lo que estaba seleccionado o escrito.

Por ejemplo:
En el Form en el que estoy tiene varios CheckBox y dejo dos seleccionados, cuando paso al "Form2" y vuelvo estos ya no están seleccionados, como puedo hacer para que cuando vuelva no me borre la selección de esos CheckBox

Cualquier metodo de realizar eso es bienvenido,Gracias!

Comment: Por qué no has aceptado ninguna respuesta en tus preguntas anteriores?

Comment: @Arriel debe ser pq no le importa, hay gente asi lamentablemente